# How do I convert userdata to a uint32 or float?

Tags: floating-point, lua, uint32

How do I convert user data like this:

```
local user_data = { 0x33, 0x22, 0x11, 0x00 }
```

to either a uint32 or float using Lua?  I cant find anything in the documentation that talks about this.

I've tried various methods and none of these have worked:

```
local data_uint32 = tonumber(user_data)
local data_uint32 = user_data:uint32()
local data_uint32 = uint32(user_data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd rather define my own function:

```
function toUInt32(user_data)
    return user_data[1] * 0x1000000
         + user_data[2] * 0x10000
         + user_data[3] * 0x100
         + user_data[4]
end
print(toUInt32(user_data))
```

Don't know any predefined library function to do this.

Note: You may want to consider the endianness of the number.